# Kotlin Unit test instantiate for each test scenario

Tags: kotlin, junit, junit-jupiter

Having a Unit test class with some arguments defined in construction

```
class VersionConsumerSpec {


    private val path = Paths.get("target").toAbsolutePath().toString()
    private val kafkaPort = (4000..8000).random()
    private val zooKeeperPort = (4000..8000).random()
    private val config: AppConfig = createAppConfig(kafkaPort)
    private val producer = createKafkaProducer()

    init {
        println("hello world")
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @ObsoleteCoroutinesApi
    @Test
    @DisplayName("test1")
    fun test1() {
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @ObsoleteCoroutinesApi
    @Test
    @DisplayName("test2")
    fun test2() {
    }

}
```

All the variables defined are executed for every test, even the `init` is executed twice here.
Then I'm having issues since I want to declare all those variables once for all test cases.

I´m going something wrong here?, in Java or Scala this is not happening.

Is like if for each test the class would be completely instantiate again and again.

Comment: Which library are you using for unit tests? Is it junit? Please add it to tags if it is the case

Comment: it's Jupiter-api 5.6.2 what do you mean with "add it to tags"???

Comment: I meant adding `junit` or `junit-jupiter` tag to the question

Comment: Did you try to initialize variables by using @BeforeAll annotation? https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.2/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/BeforeAll.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are looking for [@TestInstance](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestInstance.html) annotation. `PER_CLASS` mode allows to create a new test instance once per test class.

```
@TestInstance(PER_CLASS)
class VersionConsumerSpec {
    ...
```

Comment: yep that's what I need